# Adding a Structure element to another Structure element

Tags: c

I have been trying to add a Structure element to another structural element in C Programming Language.

Details:
Node contains [ Data, ID, Place ]
Node2 contains [ spaceAvailable ]

all of them are integers.

I am trying to assign the spaceAvailable[from Node2] to the Place[Node], After a successful assigned task the updated Node can be called by start [ start= newNode ]

But I am getting a random value always. May I have some help to solve this problem?

```
 bool AssignToPosition(Node **node, Node2 ** node2)
{    
     int data;
     int id;
     int place;
     int spaceAvailable;

    Node *newNode = *node;
    Node2 *newNode2 = *node2;

        // Allocating memory for new node
        newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode2 = (Node2 *)malloc(sizeof(Node2));

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->id = id;
        newNode->place= newNode2->spaceAvailable;
        
        Node *start = *node;
        start=newNode;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to return -1 from a function returning `bool`? As for your question, there's probably enough info to help, but you're close to having a minimal complete example, so maybe you could update your post with that. It looks like all you need to include is `Node` and `Node2`, and maybe some headers and a 'main' function.

Comment: I am returning -1 to test this function at another place in the same program. Like if(AssignToPosition== -1)
       { printf("\n I Passed Bool"); }

My main concern is to fix the updated Node. which can be called by start at the end. 
For example:  at Node data=5; id= 5695; place= null;
at Node2 spaceAvailable=16;
then the updated node newNode/start should look like 
data=5; id= 5695; place= 16; When I print the [start] by another function like  display_now(start)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.